# How can I send an data to chart.js in python django?

Tags: python, django

I'm making a project about pull a user github API like this one https://octoprofile.now.sh/user?id=nathannewyen

I don't know how to pass an data to another function in django

Here is my `views.py`:

```
def user(req, username):
    username = str.lower(username)

    # Get User Info

    with urlopen(f'https://api.github.com/users/{username}') as response:
        source = response.read()
    data = json.loads(source)

    # Get Limit Call API

    with urlopen(f'https://api.github.com/rate_limit') as response:
        source = response.read()
    limit_data = json.loads(source)

    # Get User Repo Info
    with urlopen(f'https://api.github.com/users/{username}/repos') as response:
        source = response.read()
    sorted_by_stars = json.loads(source)
    sorted_by_forks = json.loads(source)
    sorted_by_size = json.loads(source)
    # Sorted by stars

    def sort_user_repo_by_stars(sorted_by_stars):
        return sorted_by_stars['stargazers_count']

    sorted_by_stars.sort(key=sort_user_repo_by_stars, reverse=True)

    # Sorted by forks
    def sort_user_repo_by_forks(sorted_by_forks):
        return sorted_by_forks['forks']

    sorted_by_forks.sort(key=sort_user_repo_by_forks, reverse=True)

    # Sorted by size
    def sort_user_repo_by_size(sorted_by_size):
        return sorted_by_size['size']

    sorted_by_size.sort(key=sort_user_repo_by_size, reverse=True)

    created_at = data['created_at']
    created_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(created_at, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    created_at = created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y")

    context = {
        'username': username,
        'data': data,
        'created_at': created_at,
        'limit_data': limit_data,
        'sorted_by_stars': sorted_by_stars[:8],
        'sorted_by_forks': sorted_by_forks[:8],
        'sorted_by_size': sorted_by_size[:8],
    }
    return render(req, 'user.html', context)


class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        labels = ["Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
        default_items = [23, 2, 3, 12, 2]
        data = {
            "labels": labels,
            "default": default_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

and here is my `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import ChartData

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('search', views.searchUser),
    path('<username>', views.user),
    path('api/chart/data/', ChartData.as_view(), name='api-data'),
]
```

and here is my templates `index.html`:

```
<script>
    var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'
    var defaultData = []
    var labels = [];
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        success: function (data) {
            labels = data.labels
            defaultData = data.default
            setChart()
        },
        error: function (error_data) {
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    })

    function setChart() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: defaultData,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>

            <div class="card shadow">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Top Languages</h4>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <canvas id="myChart" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to make an Top languages used chart like the link that I linked below.

How can I do that in python django?

I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

To make your backend and your frontend communicate, you can use some sort of REST API between the two. This is a whole topic on its own so here is a solution to achieve what you want in a simple way.

Your django server is serving HTML files to your client. Those HTML files are called "templates" in the django world because they are rendered by your server. Sadly, once served to the client, you cannot execute python on those pages anymore... Hou have to find another way. Here is an idea:

As you can type JavaScript in an HTML file, you can make django render your data as something JavaScript can understand. JSON for example, or even directly JavaScript code. Keep in mind that this is often seen as a bad practice though, as it will make bugs harder to find.

In our case, we only need two things: `x` and `y` values.

Here is how to generate those in python, so that it can be turned into JavaScript:

```
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
values = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

return render('our_template.html', {
   'x': json.dumps(labels),
   'y': json.dumps(values),
})
```

This what we can write in our template to store the data as plain JavaScript variables:

```
let x = {{ x|safe }}; // this is django template markup language right here
let y = {{ y|safe }}; // it will get evaluated before returning the template to the client
```

The code above will get rendered as:

```
let x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

And here is how you will use them to make a simple bar chart:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
    let label = "My chart";
    let ctx = document.getElementById('my-chart').getContext('2d');
    let accessLogChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: x,
            datasets: [{
                label: label,
                data: y,
            }]
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried to add  `let x = "{{ x|safe }}"; let y = {{ y|safe }}` in my script tag but it's giving me this error `Declaration or statement expected.javascript`

Comment: Why did you put `x` between quotemarks (`"`) ? This won't work, you should remove those: `let x = "{{ x|safe }}";` becomes `let x = {{ x|safe }};`